# Loop for Selecting and Summarising Each Column for Later Permutation

Tags: r, loops, permutation

I have a dataset similar to the one below. The idea is I need to use a loop to do a permutation test for mean differences. My primary issue is I have to loop through columns in the dataset and I don't know how.

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10), nrow=5)) 
category <- rep(c("good", "bad"), c(2, 3))
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
df <- cbind(id, df, category)

  id         X1         X2 category 
1  1  0.5584823 -2.3135133     good     
2  2 -0.1115585  0.4731869     good     
3  3 -0.7435472 -0.0231894      bad      
4  4 -0.6673812  0.7470000      bad      
5  5 -1.2959973  0.4255970      bad
```

So I need to basically do this in the loops:

```
merged_df %>% filter(category == "bad") %>% select(X1) %>% summarise(mean_X_bad = mean(X1))
merged_df %>% filter(category == "good") %>% select(X2) %>% summarise(mean_X_good = mean(X1))
```

For both X1 and X2 (and 98 other X variables not shown here).

So for each X from 1 to 100 I will have to get the mean of X in group = good and the mean of X in group = bad so that I can run a loop for permutation of mean differences in the value of X between the groups for all X.

I don't know how to run a loop that selects the column and maps it to the category and returns the mean of that subset. I assume in order for the permutation to be performed I need a vector of the "good" means and the "bad" means to compare. So I guess that has to be the result of the first loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gather your data first (make it "long" instead of "wide") by using `tidyr::gather`, then summarise by grouping the categories and variables:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -id, -category) %>%
  group_by(category, variable) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value))
```

Here's the output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   category [2]
  category variable    mean
  <fct>    <chr>      <dbl>
1 bad      X1       -0.323 
2 bad      X2        0.342 
3 good     X1        0.0793
4 good     X2        0.632
```

Comment: This definitely appears to be what I need. Seems I have much more practice to do with the gather function. Can't believe it was that simple. I feel silly. Thank you!

Comment: @Michael no problem, hope it helps in your entire dataset. Reading (and doing) this part of **r4ds** helped me understand these functions: [link](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html#spreading-and-gathering)

Answer (score 0):

If we want to loop, then use `map2`.  Based on the OP's code, we are `filter`ing the 'bad', 'good' and `select`ing columns 'X1', 'X2'.  So, pass these as two `vector`s in `map2`, `filter`, `select` the dataset, and `summarise` the `mean` of the `select`ed column with a new name

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(c("bad", "good"), c("X1", "X2"), ~ 
     df %>% 
       filter(category == .x) %>% 
       select(.y) %>%
       summarise(!! paste0("mean_X_", .x) := mean(!! rlang::sym(.y))))
#[[1]]
#  mean_X_bad
#1 -0.4954794

#[[2]]
#  mean_X_good
#1   0.7497338
```

---

Instead of `filter`ing by 'category, it can be `group`ed and then use `summarise_at`

```
df %>%
   group_by(category) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(matches("^X\\d+$")), mean)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  category       X1     X2
#  <fct>       <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 bad       0.228   -0.438
#2 good     -0.00465  0.355
```

and that gives the same output without any `gather`ing (only the results are transposed in `gather`ing)

```
 df %>%
    gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -id, -category) %>%
    group_by(category, variable) %>%
   summarise(mean = mean(value))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   category [2]
#  category variable     mean
#  <fct>    <chr>       <dbl>
#1 bad      X1        0.228  
#2 bad      X2       -0.438  
#3 good     X1       -0.00465
#4 good     X2        0.355
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10), nrow=5)) 
category <- rep(c("good", "bad"), c(2, 3))
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
df <- cbind(id, df, category)
```

Comment: This is very cool, but it seems to only work for the example. My data set has 2 categories but 100 X values, X_1 through X_100. The map2 functions seems to require .x and .y be equal length?

Comment: @Michael Can you check the second block of code with `summarise_at`

Comment: Also, for my edification, can you explain what the exclamation marks are doing exactly and what is the meaning of :=?

Comment: @Michael  It is an assignment operator used to create a column.  If you have used `data.table`, there is the same one for creating column by reference.  But, here in tidyverse context, its behavior is different although it creates a column and evaluates the expression on the lhs as a string for new column name

Comment: @Michael You can also check [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html) for more understanding

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that function. I'm quite new to coding/R. I tried this:

df %>% filter(category == "bad") %>% select(X1) %>% summarise_at(category, mean_X_bad = mean(X1))
Error in mean(X1) : object 'X1' not found

Doubt I used it correctly?

Comment: thanks so much for the link to "advanced r." that will be very helpful once I get these basics down!

Comment: @Michael  If you are selecting only a single column, you don't need `summarise_at`., but this works `df %>% filter(category == "bad") %>% select(X1) %>%summarise_at(vars(X1), mean)`

Comment: I tried to do this:

merged_df %>% filter(category == "bad") %>% select(starts_with("g")) %>%summarise_at(vars(merged_df[,c(-1, -102)]), mean)

but it returned an error that makes no sense: Error: `merged_df[, c(-1, -102)]` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a list

How is merged_df[, c(-1, -102)] coming back as a list? Basically the variables are columns 2 through 101 of the dataset.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something? This answer is very complicated. I don't think that @Michael needs to enquo/bang bang anything here. It's a simple `gather`,  `group_by`, and `summarise` problem

Comment: @MarianMinar  The second or first one?  If it is the second, it is the standard way of doing this for multiple columns.  Check the output of your `gather` with  this.  There is no need for reshaping

Comment: @MarianMinar  You can check the output of `gather` based and my second approach.